# MassTransit Courier resends activity after a while

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I implemented routing slip with a bunch of activities. One of them performs long-running process in Azure that takes even 15-20min. I noticed that after 10 minutes, while the process is still running, the activity gets executed again. It breaks the whole routing slip, because the first process is still in progress and a retry produces an error.

I am using Azure Service Bus as a message broker. I couldn't find any reference to this topic in the documentation so I'm wondering whether this is specific to the Courier and it can be changed so that it does not redeliver at all or is this some kind of an incorecct behaviour?

EDIT:

Here's the code after the changes:

```
services.AddMassTransit(c =>
{
    c.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new DefaultEndpointNameFormatter(false));

    c.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<TestConsumer>();

    c.AddActivitiesFromNamespaceContaining<ActivityBase<IArguments, LogBase>>();
    
    c.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection_string"));
        
        cfg.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25);
        cfg.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25);
        cfg.MaxDeliveryCount = 1;
        
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is likely being redelivered by Azure Service Bus, due to the length of time required to consume the message.

On the receive endpoint, the `MaxAutoRenewDuration` is used to adjust the maximum time to renew the message lock, which is passed directly to the Azure client library. The default value is five minutes, which is the same as the default `LockDuration`. You can increase this time to the maximum expected time for the activity to complete.

Optionally, you can change the `MaxDeliveryCount` property to 1, so that Azure will only attempt to the deliver the message once, after which if the lock times out and is not renewed, it will move the message to the dead-letter queue for that receive endpoint.

UPDATE: If you're configuring this in an Activity Definition, you can do so as shown:

```csharp
public class CustomActivityDefinition :
    ActivityDefinition<TActivity, TArguments, TLog>
{
    protected override void ConfigureExecuteActivity(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IExecuteActivityConfigurator<TActivity, TArguments> executeActivityConfigurator)
    {
        if(endpointConfigurator is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
        {
            sb.MaxDeliveryCount = 1;
            sb.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(67);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I inserted the code to the question. It still did not work like expected and after 10min I still get the activity redelivered. Do I have to use `cfg.ReceiveEndpoint()` or is it possible to modify this configuration so I could still use `cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx)` instead?

Comment: You can create an activity [definition](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/definitions.html) (derived from `ActivityDefinition<,,>`, not shown) that configures the execute/compensate endpoints. The AddActivities... method will find them in the namespace and apply them while configuring endpoints.

Comment: Could you show me some code example of how do I configure endpoints in that definition? I can't find anything in the documentation and I don't even know whether I should do it in the constructor or by overriding `ConfigureExecuteActivity` method. I also tried to find those options using Intellisense but that didn't help either.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of this kind of configuration, but now it works as expected, thanks!